# Help my dear Friend!

Tags: cipher

My friend has been Kidnapped! You must find him at a location. The kiddnapper gave me a hint:

> iuay hyptqg pf du ukt sxdcd qi, qi

Please help him!

Comment: try and figure out how to directly translate it without using quip quip or anything like that and you get an upvote

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By using [quipqiup](https://quipqiup.com/) with a little help from me by guessing some of the words, I get

> Your friend is at [The Plaza NY](https://www.theplazany.com/), NY

Comment: But can you figure my startegy to encode it?

Comment: Now that you have unveiled it in a comment to another answer, I bet I wouldn't have figured it out since my keyboard is not a QWERTY one.

Comment: oh. Well most keyboards are qwerty, so I figured most people would be able to get it. Anyway congrats for finding an another way for finding the answer!

Comment: Not sure qwerty is the most often used keyboard layout in the world, but on an English-speaking website, yes, one may safely assume that most (80-90%) keyboards are qwerty.

Comment: very true, very true.

Answer (score 4):

> I=Y
>  
>      Yoay hyptqg pf du ukt sxdcd qY, qY
>  
>  Y=R
>  
>      YoaR hRptqg pf du ukt sxdcd qY, qY
>  
>  A=U
>  
>      YoUR hRptqg pf du ukt sxdcd qY, qY
>  
>  H=F
>  
>      YoUR FRptqg pf du ukt sxdcd qY, qY
>  
>  P=I
>  
>      YoUR FRItqg If du ukt sxdcd qY, qY
>  
>  T=E
>  
>      YoUR FRIEqg If du ukE sxdcd qY, qY
>  
>  Q=N
>  
>      YoUR FRIENg If du ukE sxdcd NY, NY
>  
>  U=T
>  
>      YoUR FRIENg If dT TkE sxdcd NY, NY
>  
>  K=H
>  
>      YoUR FRIENg If dT THE sxdcd NY, NY
>  
>  D=A
>  
>      YoUR FRIENg If AT THE sxAcA NY, NY
>  
>  G=D
>  
>      YoUR FRIEND If AT THE sxAcA NY, NY
>  
>  F=S
>  
>      YoUR FRIEND IS AT THE sxAcA NY, NY
>  
>  S=P
>  
>      YoUR FRIEND IS AT THE PxAcA NY, NY
>  
>  X=L
>  
>      YoUR FRIEND IS AT THE PLAcA NY, NY
>  
>  C=Z
>  
>      YoUR FRIEND IS AT THE PLAZA NY, NY
>  
>  O is still an O

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! First of all, please hide your answer inside spoiler tags, to avoid spoiling the solution for anyone who wants to have a go at the puzzle themselves (I appreciate it might be difficult given how many paragraphs this answer is split into). Secondly, could you explain how you worked out what each letter is mapped to? This isn't a complete answer unless you can explain your working.

Comment: Oops! that O was supposed to be An I

Comment: I mean An a I fixed it. Since you got It second I won't accept it but I will upvote it. the pattern was supposed to be I took a letter then I moved it Two spaces to the left as a keyboard transfer